# What is the way to do text for functions?

Tags: fonts, formatting, font-encodings

I would prefer not to have a bunch of   \newcommands  or whatever can I just do text{}  or something?

Comment: Is `\textnormal` what you’re looking for? Could you maybe give us a more specific example?

Comment: @Davislor 

I would prefer to get the same kind of text as in \log \sin \cos  etc

Comment: -1: Very unclear and low effort question especially considering it's your **36th question**. Even the tags do not make sens (no `math`, instead `fonts`, `formatting`, and `font-encodings`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You clarify in a comment, “I would prefer to get the same kind of text as in `\log` `\sin` `\cos` etc.”  That’s the `\operatorname` command from `amsmath`, e.g. `\operatorname{min}`.  You can also `\DeclareMathOperator{\min}{min}` and write `\min`.

This gives the word you type the same spacing as sin, log and so on, which might not be what you want.  Either `\mathrm` or `\textnormal` might be instead.  The former typesets upright letters in math mode, gobbling spaces and so on.  The latter switches back to text mode temporarily, and lets you insert short phrases like “ if ” and “ for all ”.  By default, all of these will be the same font, but it is possible to change any of them.